# Shopify buy-sdk in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, shopify

I try to build Shopify end point shop application in Xmaramin.

Shopify provides native buy-sdk for Android and IOS which handle communication with API, therefore I was thinking about writing some in-app API based on interface that is implemented in projects for particular OS calling native library and communicate with Xamarin app.

I found some native libraries/wrappers for Shopify that covers API in version 2 which was realized in RESTful technology. Unfortunately version 3  API is realized using GraphQL. I cant't find any Xamarin lib which using Shopify API version 3.

I try to create BindingsLibrary project based on buy-sdk AAR file but output library don't contains all classes few examples below:

[image]

I try write Android project that hides calls to sdk but it don't work either.

Is there any solution to use Shopify buy-sdk in Xamarin project?